# Insert datetime into url for curl php google calendar api

Tags: php, curl, google-calendar-api

How can insert datetime format RFC 3339 on a url?  i already try use a variable on url like this but its still return bad request.

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin='$date'";
```

but when i try without using variable like this, it works.

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2019-06-03T10:00:00-07:00";
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) tool of php string :

```php
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/...?blabla=" . $str_date;
```

make sure that you're `$date` variable is in the appropriate format. you can change it using [date_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

#### EDIT

In your case you should use:

```php
$str_date = date_format($date, \DateTime::RFC3339);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have already set my $date as $date=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP'); but still bad request.

Comment: yes but this format won't render a date that look like this `2019-06-03T10:00:00-07:00`as in your second string

Comment: I've updated my answer with the appropriate format, tell me if it worked

Answer (score -1):

Just use this :

```
$daterfc=date("c", strtotime($date));
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events? 
maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=".$daterfc;
```

Reference [PHP Date Format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it still count as a bad request

Comment: @JimmyPurnawan I have updated the answer, kindly check. Was missing =.

Comment: i dont know but i still can't get the event list with a variable

Comment: @JimmyPurnawan It is working kindly check, I have checked it twice. You must be doing something wrong.